# How to create bucketed tensors from TensorFlow Dataset object?

Tags: tensorflow

I created an `TextLineDataset` object using following code:

```
dataset = TextLineDataset([text_path])
```

Then I want to create bucketed tensors from this Dataset. I know there is an API called `bucket_by_sequence_length`. I tried to feed this API with iterator by calling `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`, but it did not work. How should I feed `input_length` and `tensors` arguments of `bucket_by_sequence_length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As result of some investigation, I found that `bucket_by_sequence_length` is designed to process tensors, which could be enqueued into `Queue`s. But `iterator` of `Dataset` is different.

Then I found that `Dataset` support `group_by_window` operation, which could be used to generate bucketed dataset.

Answer (score -3):

Once you have the Dataset object you can use the following code to generate batches using the API bucket_by_sequence_length.

```
# This will be used by bucket_by_sequence_length to batch them according to their length.
def _element_length_fn(x, y=None):
    return array_ops.shape(x)[0]


# These are the upper length boundaries for the buckets.
# Based on these boundaries, the sentences will be shifted to different buckets.
boundaries = [upper_boundary_for_batch] # Here you will have to define the upper boundaries for different buckets. You can have as many boundaries as you want. But make sure that the upper boundary contains the maximum length of the sentence that is in your dataset.

# These defines the batch sizes for different buckets.
# I am keeping the batch_size for each bucket same, but this can be changed based on more analysis.
# As per the documentation - batch size per bucket. Length should be len(bucket_boundaries) + 1.
# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/bucket_by_sequence_length
batch_sizes = [batch_size] * (len(boundaries) + 1)

# Bucket_by_sequence_length returns a dataset transformation function that has to be applied using dataset.apply.
# Here the important parameter is pad_to_bucket_boundary. If this is set to true then, the sentences will be padded to
# the bucket boundaries provided. If set to False, it will pad the sentences to the maximum length found in the batch.
# Default value for padding is 0, so we do not need to supply anything extra here.
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(_element_length_fn, boundaries,
                                                                       batch_sizes,
                                                                       drop_remainder=True,
                                                                       pad_to_bucket_boundary=True))
```